# Geo location emulation? (Web sites)

Tags: url, web, geolocation

How to emulate that i open web site from another geo location? For example i am in Brazzaville and i want to open web site like i am in USA, or Spain?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is to do performance checking, there are a number of services that allow this.  I've used [dotcom-monitor](http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/) in the past for pre-production testing.

Comment: Thank you for info Bob! but it is not free.

Comment: Try their free instant test - http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/task_instant_test.aspx